# Webpack error: "ERROR in chunk main [entry] bundle.js this is not a typed array."

Tags: javascript, webpack

I for some reason can't find anywhere online discussing this webpack issue. I am very new to webpack (and, incidentally, React), so any help would be very appreciated as I'm sure there's just something I'm overlooking.  When I compile my React app using webpack, everything runs smoothly, except for an unhelpful error at the very end:

```
Time: 2102ms
   [0] ./~/process/browser.js 5.3 kB {0} [built]
   [5] ./~/react/react.js 56 bytes {0} [built]
  [72] ./~/redux/es/index.js 1.08 kB {0} [built]
 [121] ./~/redux/es/utils/warning.js 637 bytes {0} [built]
 [123] ./src/web/reducers/reducer.js 842 bytes {0} [built]
 [124] ./~/react-dom/index.js 59 bytes {0} [built]
 [125] ./src/index.css 907 bytes {0} [built]
 [130] ./src/web/containers/NewPostHandler.js 1 kB {0} [built]
 [131] ./~/css-loader!./src/index.css 290 bytes {0} [built]
 [185] ./~/react-dom/lib/ReactDOM.js 5.14 kB {0} [built]
 [259] ./~/react-router/lib/index.js 3.62 kB {0} [built]
 [276] ./~/redux/es/bindActionCreators.js 1.98 kB {0} [built]
 [277] ./~/redux/es/combineReducers.js 5.58 kB {0} [built]
 [279] ./~/style-loader/addStyles.js 7.15 kB {0} [built]
 [285] ./src/index.js 718 bytes {0} [built]
    + 271 hidden modules

ERROR in chunk main [entry]
bundle.js
this is not a typed array.
```

Here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname,'/src'),
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'svg-url-loader'
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Here are the relevant bits of my `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.21.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "react-scripts": "0.7.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0-rc.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "normalizr": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "^15.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.6",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "redux": "^3.6.0"
  },
```

The `index.js` file is nothing special, but in case it's needed:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import hello_world from './web/reducers/reducer.js'
import Root from './web/components/Root'
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

let store = createStore(hello_world)

import './index.css';
ReactDOM.render(
  <Root store={store} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting this same error this morning. I updated my node version to 7.2 and am no longer getting this error.

Comment: Yep, that was it thank you! I had already tried updating node via `apt-get` (Ubuntu), but was told that v4.2.6 was the current version. If anyone else runs into this, update the node repos first (consult https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/, `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -` was the command I needed).